# Problem executing docker exec command from php

Tags: php, docker

I am trying to execute a command in a **R-base Docker** container and get the output parsed by my PHP code, if I run the docker sentence in console it works but in php it return an empty response.

The script that I want to run is:

```
docker exec -w /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/webroot/code -it R_3.5.3 Rscript my_script.R /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/webroot/media/transfer/tmp/filetoparse.txt
```

**It works fine in console** because the output is:

```
[{"id":"C1","type":"CONSTANT","value":"C1",....]
```

If I store the output in a var and then I do echo of it I can see the result, so the output is in the main console:

```
myvar=`docker exec -w /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/webroot/code -it R_3.5.3 Rscript my_script.R /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/webroot/media/transfer/tmp/filetoparse.txt`
echo $myvar
>>[{"id":"C1","type":"CONSTANT","value":"C1",....]
```

Well my **problem** is when I want to call the script from **php served by apache**:
I tried:

```
exec("docker exec -w /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/webroot/code -it R_3.5.3 Rscript my_script.R /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/webroot/media/transfer/tmp/filetoparse.txt", $outputs);
debug($outputs);
```

The result is:

```
APP/Controller/MyController.php (line 56)
''
```

I tried to log the output in a file but, nothing, so what I think is that the R script is not executing.

Any clue about what could be happening?

**Note**: apache user is added to Docker's group amd I logged with it and I can execute the script in console.

Comment: Does the process running your webserver have permission to run `docker` commands? Probably not, probably for the best

Comment: Also `-it` is interactable, you probably do not want your process to hang on the command if unnecessary

Comment: me bad, it was the -it param T.T thanks a lot!